# CSS not working properly in Internet Explorer? (absolute positioning)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, compatibility

Plenty of other things on the page are using the absolute positioning as well, but for some reason the "vote" and "profile" buttons are displaying several hundred pixels to the right and about fifty pixels up in Internet Explorer 9/10 (8- is not an issue here).  There is no styling in the HTML, it's all right here.  Anything that stands out?  Thanks!

```
        .contain{
        margin-left:-65px;
        margin-top:-85px;
        position:absolute;

    }
    .video_display1{
        background-color:#333;
        width:250px;
        height:200px;
        margin-top:40px;
        margin-left:88px;
    display:inline;
    }
    .profile1{
        width:49px;
        height:12px;
        margin-left:87px;
        margin-top:3px;
        position:absolute;
    }
    .vote1{
        margin-top:3px;
        margin-left:240px;
        position:absolute;
    }
    .display_vote1{
        margin-left:295px;
        margin-top:2px;
        font-size:11px;
        position:absolute;
    }
```

And here's the HTML:

```
            <span class="contain">
                <iframe class="video_display1" width="250" height="200" src=""> </span>
                <span class="profile1"><img src=''/></span>     
                <span class="vote1"><input type="image" src=''/></span>             
                <span class="display_vote1"></span>
            </span>
```

And the DOCTYPE:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Can we see the HTML? Do you have a jsFiddle?

Comment: do you have the correct doctype?

Comment: I don't have a jsFiddle, but I added the HTML, and the doctype.  Thanks for your time, guys.

Comment: i have created this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4cdxP/ but not seeing anything. added borders. can you go through and try to simplfy and isolate the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used JFiddle and wasn't aware how straightforward it was.  That's bizarre.  I guess it's back to the drawing board, because there's obviously something funky going on here.

Comment: oh i see now. span can't get height and width because its inline element. try using divs.

Comment: @user2024011 jsFiddle is awesome, you will catch on pretty quickly

Comment: @user2024011 play with this http://jsfiddle.net/4cdxP/2/

Comment: @user2024011 i updated it again. if you try to do things this way it will get much easier to understand where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined width and height of images, so to get fixed height & width define it first. And use `display: inline-block;` in your `.contain` then only you get what you want.